# How best to create unit tests (using Mocha, Chai) for a Sequelize function such as .findAll()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, node-sqlite3

I am in a programming bootcamp and we are currently learning about fullstack JavaScript. We are using the Express framework and I have opted to use a SQLite3 database. This is a basic app for maintaining books at a local community center. I am required to write up to 3 unit tests and the one that I am having difficulty with is the **GET /** route. This route is intended to pull data from the database and render them to create a list of books currently in the database when you visit the *root route*.

I want to test whether the **bookList** variable containing the *awaited* `Book.findAll()` **Sequelize** function is actually sending an array of objects containing row data to the Pug template engine to render the list of books.

When I host locally, this is working as intended. I am just puzzled on how to have that reflected in my unit tests. I've attached the `routes/index.js`, `views/index.pug` & the `test/readOp_test.js` containing all of my tests including the one for the **GET /** route. Please let me know if I need to share more of the code and will reply with what is needed for anyone willing to help me.

---

**readOp_test.js**

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHTTP = require('chai-http');
let chaiPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
let application = require('../app');
let expect = require('chai').expect;
chai.use(chaiHTTP);
chai.use(chaiPromised);
chai.should();

// Unit Test Suite
describe('Unit Tests for Endpoints to meet Code Louisville Project Requirements', () => {
    //Test Spec for READ ALL operation


    
    /* it('should pull data from all rows in the database', (done) => {
        chai.request(application)
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.body.should.be.a('object');
                done();
            })
    }); */

    //Test Spec for READ-by-id operation
    it('should pull data from the below id', (done) => {
        const id = 2;
        chai.request(application)
            .get(`/${id}`)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.body.should.be.a('object');
                done();
            })
    });
    it('should return status 404 when READING the below id which is not in the database', (done) => {
        const id = 12;
        chai.request(application)
            .get(`/${id}`)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(404);
                done();
            })
    });
    //Test Spec for CREATE operation
    it('shouldnt POST the below book entry since the title value is an empty string.', async() => {
        let res = await chai
        .request(application)
        .post('/')
        .type('form')
        .send({title: '', author: "al-Gibber", genre: "Math", language: "Arabic"})

        expect(res.status).to.equal(500)
    });
    it('should POST the below book entry since all properties contain actual string values.', async() => {
        let res = await chai
        .request(application)
        .post('/')
        .type('form')
        .send({title: 'Gibberish', author: "al-Gibber", genre: "Math", language: "Arabic"})

        expect(res.status).to.equal(200)
    });
});
```

**routes/index.js**

```
// Requiring Express to enable access to the framework's methods, properties, & other tools.
const express = require('express');
// Router handles HTTP requests.
const router = express.Router();
// These two variables are ensuring `routes/index.js` has access to the database & its models.
const db = require('../db');
const { Book } = db.models;



//This is a convenient function that handles async/await.
function asyncHandler(cb){
    return async(req, res, next) => {
        try {
        await cb(req, res, next)
        } catch(error){
        // Forward error to the global error handler
        next(error);
        }
    }
}



//This route handles the initial load of the app, the root route, & will draw data from each row in the database & display it on the homepage.
//This route is a READ operation distinctly a READ ALL operation.
router.get('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const bookList = await Book.findAll();
    //The use of .render() method ensures that the `index.pug` template is rendered when user visits the root directory.
    //{ bookList } is an object containing data from each row in the database to be used in the Pug template.
    res.render('index', {bookList});
}));



//This route handles adding a book to the app's database by rendering the newBook.pug template which contains a form to collect the column data for the database.
//This route is the beginning of the CREATE operation for this app.
router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('newBook', { book: {}});
});

//This route handles the data collected by newBook.pug's form. It creates the database entry and posts the data.
//This route is the closure for the CREATE operation for this app.
router.post('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    let book;
    try {
        book = await Book.create(req.body);
        console.log(book);
        res.redirect('/');
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}));



//This route handles rendering found data for each book that would be clicked on in the index.pug template.
//This route is another distinct READ operation that is reading an entry's data based on the primary key ID selected on index.pug.
router.get("/:id", asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const book = await Book.findByPk(req.params.id);
    if(book) {
      res.render("bookViewing", { book });  
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  })); 



//Ensures that all routes written in this folder can be used in the root's `app.js` file.
module.exports = router;
```

**index.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Library
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/static/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    div#app
      div#container
        h1 Library
        h2 Our Book Selection
        
        each book in bookList
          book
            p
              span= book.title
              | 
              a(href=`/${book.id}`) Learn More

        p This library is open to all in our local community!
        a(href="/new") Add New Book
```

**Screenshot of the correctly rendered `index.pug` template**

### [Screenshot of rendered PUG template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFySP.png)